# Bootstrap не масштабируется окно на телефоне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Сделал страничку на бутстрапе - [www.shumik.zzz.com.ua/calc3](http://www.shumik.zzz.com.ua/calc3)  блок по центре - по боках ничего нет, если скролить в браузере - всё нормально, container изменяет размер, но при открытии с телефона вся страница отдаляется, видно ее почти полностью и по бокам белые полосы, а надо чтоб на весь экран. Как можно исправить?

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать проверку на устройство

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Базовый шаблон Bootstrap должен содержать эту строку 
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!